# Receive events from multiple HTML5 videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I have multiple videos and want to get an event from all of them. But I get only the event from one of them (tested in Chrome). Why?

HTML:

```
<video id="video1" preload="auto" src="video1.ogg"></video>
<video id="video2" preload="auto" src="video2.ogg"></video>
```

JS:

```
$('video').on('canplay', function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A5uKw/2/)

**EDIT:**

Ok.. it is really strange. On the very first load I get sometimes both events. But after that on every reload I get just an event from one of them!? Here a screenshot of my console:

[image]

Comment: I get `canplay` twice - are you sure it's not something else?  Anyway the `.each()` is unnecessary.

Comment: Hey, yeah the .each() was unnecessary but just a leftover from code reduction. I've updated my post. But it isn't working and it's really strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the 'canplay' event has already fired by the time you register it. I believe this is because jsFiddle wraps your code inside of `$(window).load(...`. If you were to move the script into the html, like on [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/y4uTr/1/), it should work.

Most of the time, if you know for sure that your script is going to run synchronously right after the video element is created with a `src`, you can assume that none of those events have been fired. But, just to be safe, and especially when you don't know how your code will be used, I recommend something like this:

```
function handleCanplay(video) {
    console.log($(video).attr('id'));
};

$('video').each(function () {
    //first, check if we missed the 'canplay' event
    if (this.readyState >= this.HAVE_FUTURE_DATA) {
        //yup, we missed it, so run this immediately.
        handleCanplay(this);
    } else {
        //no, we didn't miss it, so listen for it
        $(this).on('canplay', function () {
            handleCanplay(this);
        });
    }
});
```

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6uG9J/5/).